# c++ - Where to define functions of nested class?

Tags: c++, scope, nested

I can't wrap my head around the concept of using nested classes in c++.

I am trying to create an iterator for my linked list. I have declared it as a nested class within the private scope of LinkedList.h

But where do I define the functions of the class Iterator? Right now, I'm trying to do so in the bottom of the file, along with all of LinkedList's functions. But no matter how I try to twist and spin the scope definitions, I can't get it to work. Am I supposed to be doing this differently?

The Iterator class

```
class Iterator {

    private:

        LinkedList<T>* l;
        Node<T>* node;

    public:

        Iterator(LinkedList<T> *ll, Node<T> *n);        
        T get();
        int hasNext();
        void moveNext();

    };
```

The four function definitions

```
template <typename T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T>::Iterator(LinkedList<T> *ll, Node<T> *n) {
    l = ll;
    node = n;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T>::get() {
    return node->getData();
}

template <typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T>::hasNext() {
    return node->getNext();
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T>::moveNext() {
    node = node->getNext();
}
```

The errors I'm getting are:

"use of undefined type: LinkedList::Iterator"

"syntax error: unexpected type LinkedList"

"syntax error: missing ';' before '{'"

and many more.

I am so very, very lost.

edit:

The LinkedList.h file in its entirety:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#include "Node.h"
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class LinkedList : public List {

private:

    int n;
    Node<T> *first;
    Node<T> *last;

    template <typename T>
    class Iterator {

    private:

        LinkedList<T>* l;
        Node<T>* node;

    public:

        Iterator(LinkedList<T> *ll, Node<T> *n);        
        T get();
        int hasNext();
        void moveNext();

    };

public:

    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList & ll);
    ~LinkedList();
    int size();
    void clear();
    void addFirst(T data);
    void addLast(T data);
    T removeFirst();
    T removeLast(); 
    T getFirst();
    T getLast();
    Node<T>* getFirstNode() const;
    void addAt(int pos, T data);
    T removeAt(int pos);
    T getAt(int pos);   
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList<T> &right);
    T operator[](int i);
    LinkedList& operator+(const LinkedList<T> &right);
    LinkedList& operator+=(const LinkedList<T> &right);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const LinkedList<T> & ll);
    typename LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T> getIterator();
    void mergeSort();   
};

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() {
        this->n = 0;
        this->first = 0;
        this->last = 0;
    }

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList & ll) {
    this-> n = 0;
    this-> first = 0;
    this-> last = 0;

    Node *temp = ll.first;

    while(temp) {
        addLast(temp->getData());
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }

}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::addFirst(T data) {
    Node<T> *p = new Node<T>(data, first);
    first = p;
    if(!n)
        last = p;
    n++;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::addLast(T data) {
    Node<T> *p = new Node<T>(data, 0);
    if(!n)
        first = last = p;
    else {
        last->next = p;
        last = p;
    }
    n++;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::removeFirst() {
    T a = 0;
    if(!n)
        throw "Can't retrieve element from empty list!";
    a = first->getData();
    Node<T> *p = first->next;
    delete first;
    first = p;
    n--;
    return a;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::removeLast() {
    T a = 0;
    if(!n)
        throw "Can't retrieve element from empty list!";
    if(n == 1) {
        a = last->getData();
        delete first;
        first = last = 0;
    }
    else {
        a = last->getData();
        Node<T> *p = first;
        while(p->next->next != 0)
            p = p->next;
        delete p->next;
        p->next = 0;
        last = p;
    }
    n--;
    return a;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::getFirst() {
    if(n < 1)
        throw "Can't retrieve element from empty list!";
    return first->getData();
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::getLast() {
    if(n < 1)
        throw "Can't retrieve element from empty list!";
    return last->getData();
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* LinkedList<T>::getFirstNode() const {
    return first;
}

template <typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::size() {
    return n;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::getAt(int pos) {
    if(pos >= n)
        throw "Element index out of bounds!";       
    Node<T> *temp = first;
    while(pos > 0) {
        temp = temp->next;
        pos--;
    }
    return temp->getData();     
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear() {
    Node<T> *current = first;
    while(current) {
        Node<T> *next = current->next;
        delete current;
        if(next)
            current = next;
        else
            current = 0;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::addAt(int pos, T data) {
    if(pos >= n)
        throw "Element index out of bounds!";       
    if(pos == 0)
        addFirst(data);
    else {
        Node<T> *temp = first;
        while(pos > 1) {
            temp = temp->next;
            pos--;
        }
        Node<T> *p = new Node<T>(data, temp->next);
        temp-> next = p;
        n++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::removeAt(int pos) {
    if(pos >= n)
        throw "Element index out of bounds!";       
    if(pos == 0)
        return removeFirst();
    if(pos == n - 1)
        return removeLast();
    else {
        Node<T> *p = first;
        while(pos > 1) {
            p = p->next;
            pos--;
        }
        T a = p->next->getData();
        Node<T> *temp = p->next;
        p->next = p->next->next;
        delete temp;
        n--;
        return a;
    }       
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
    clear();
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>& LinkedList<T>::operator=(const LinkedList<T> &right) {
    if(this != &right) {

        n = 0;
        first = 0;
        last = 0;

        Node<T> *temp = right.first;
        while(temp) {
            addLast(temp->getData());
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }           
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::operator[](int i) {
    return getAt(i);
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>& LinkedList<T>::operator+(const LinkedList<T> &right) {
    Node<T> *temp = right.first;
    while(temp) {
        addLast(temp->getData());
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>& LinkedList<T>::operator+=(const LinkedList<T> &right) {
    Node<T> *temp = right.first;
    while(temp) {
        addLast(temp->getData());
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const LinkedList<T> &ll) {
    Node<T> *temp = ll.getFirstNode();
    while(temp) {
        os<<temp->getData()<<std::endl;
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }
    return os;
}

template <typename T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T>::Iterator(LinkedList<T> *ll, Node<T> *n) {
    l = ll;
    node = n;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T>::get() {
    return node->getData();
}

template <typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T>::hasNext() {
    return node->getNext();
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T>::moveNext() {
    node = node->getNext();
}

template <typename T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Iterator<T> LinkedList<T>::getIterator() {
    return new Iterator<T>(*this, *first);
}

#endif
```

Comment: `Iterator` isn't a nested class in your snippet.

Comment: When you say at the bottom, do you mean at the bottom of the header file?

Comment: Isn't it a nested class if the keyword "class" (and it's code block) comes within some other class declaration? If I am to define Iterator's functions in their entirety within the class block, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Yes. At the bottom of the header file. Much like all of LinkedList's functions are defined there (This was the solution I got to work with a templated design)

Comment: OK. then can you show us the linked list class. with how you nested it.

Comment: I added the entire file in the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Shouldn't the iterator use the template typename of the the LinkedList class. If not then you need to use a different typename since it will shadow it.

Comment: It should. It seems I haven't really understood the full workings of c++ templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to use the template typename of the LinkedList class (which makes sense). That means you don't need a separate template typename for the Iterator class.

```
template <typename T>
class Iterator {
```

should be just

```
class Iterator {
```

And then the members will be defined like

```
template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::Iterator::get() {
```

---

**OR** if you really need a different typename for Iterator. Then at least you have to change the name from `T` because it will shadow the one for `LinkedList`. Something like

```
template <typename V>
class Iterator {
    ...
    V get();
    ...
```

And the memeber declarations will take the form

```
template <typename T>
template <typename V>
V LinkedList<T>::Iterator<V>::get() {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think it's working now.

As a related question: How do I even utilize the getIterator() function in my main? I can't assign it to a type Iterator, as it's a private, nested type, right?

Comment: I think you don't have a member iterator in your linkedList class. It has the class definition in it. But it hasn't declared an object of that type in it. You might need something like `Iterator iter` as a member of LinkedList

Comment: And then initialize it by passing the owner linked list to it. So then the LinkedList and the Iterator instances know each other. But pay attention to the order of initialization. The 'iter' memeber should be initialized after all list related stuff is done. like copying....

Comment: And if this solved your problem don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: I was not aware of the whole "accept answer" bit, but have done so now. Thank you so much! The part about having an Iterator as a class member make so much sense and I feel sort of dumb for not realizing that myself earlier. I'll have to try and get it to work later.

Comment: :D you have accepted someone else's answer. I am assuming that's the one that solved the problem.

Comment: So I thought I'd do something like 

this->iter = new LinkedList<T>::Iterator(this, first);

in the constructor for the LinkedList.

But then I realized: How am I going to have more than one iterator for the list then?

Comment: Oh I see. The just disregard my previous comment. I see my mistake now. What you are trying to do is very similar to the STL containers (vector. list...). Then I think you don't need the getIterator() function at all. And also you need methods that will return an iterator initialized to the begining and to the end of a a LinkedList. See how the std::vector, std::list begin() and end() work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it:

```
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::Iterator::Iterator(LinkedList<T> *ll, Node<T> *n) {
  l = ll;
  node = n;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::Iterator::get() {
  return node->getData();
}

template <typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::Iterator::hasNext() {
  return node->getNext();
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::Iterator::moveNext()
{
  node = node->getNext();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get errors, but way fewer :)

I get:

"use of class template requires template argument list" for the constructor

"unable to match definition to an existing declaration" for the constructor

"'get' is not a function"

Comment: As per somebody else's suggestion, removing the template for the Iterator class (and fixing an annoying little typo with "get") solved this. Thank you guys!